# Meta transaction with web3

Tags: metamask, raw-transaction, meta-transactions

iam just wondering. Are meta transactions not the same like raw transactions, which are signed by the user in frontend and send to a backend, where the transaction gets deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta-transactions are different because if a user signs a transaction and forwards it to a meta-tx relay which broadcasts it to the network (`sendRawTransaction()`), the signer account would still be charged for gas computation, not the meta-tx relay.

The purpose of meta-transactions is to lower barrier adoption by enabling ether-less account to interact with smart contract. Basically another account acts as a relay to forward the transaction and bear the cost of the transaction fees (gas).

**Example:** An ether-less account `account_x` wants to send a transaction to a contract `account_y` (`MyContract.myMethod()`) via the meta-tx relay owner of a funded `account_z`.

i. `account_x` extracts the bytes-code from the smart contract transaction he wants to perform

```
var txdata = MyContract.myMethod().encodeABI();
```

ii. `account_x` signs with his private key the message `sha3(txdata)`

```
var signature = await web3.eth.personal.sign(message, account_x);
```

iii. `account_x` sends the following information to the relay

```
POST https://metatx-relay.net/sendtx
{
   "txdata": txdata,
   "from": account_x,
   "to": account_y,
   "msg": message,
   "signature": signature
}
```

iv. The relay backend gets the message and checks the signature

```
var accountRecovered = web3.eth.accounts.recover(req.body.message,req.body.signature)
if(accountRecovered == req.body.from) { // good to go }
```

v. The relay backend sends the transaction to MyContract (`account_y`) using it funded account `account_z`

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: account_z,
    to: req.body.to,
    data: req.body.txdata
}).then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

**Caveats:** This is a very simplified flow !!!

- No `msg.sender` possible

The transaction is sent and paid by the relay, so it's not possible to use the alias `msg.sender` in the smart contract to identify the original sender `account_x`.

- The meta-tx relay is centralized and transaction requests could be censored

Building a network of relays with reward mechanism would be the way to go I believe where transaction request are randomly assigned to a relay.

See [BouncerProxy contract](https://github.com/austintgriffith/bouncer-proxy/blob/master/BouncerProxy/BouncerProxy.sol)

- Whitelisted accounts.

**Reference:**

- Thanks to Austin Griffith [for his work](https://medium.com/@austin_48503/ethereum-meta-transactions-90ccf0859e84): a working prototype of a meta-tx relay network with reward mechanism (economic incentive) and whitelisted addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this article. There is a detailed explanation of how meta transactions work, a link to a GitHub repository, and a demo online: https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-free-transactions-meta-transactions-explained-f829509a462d